# I need to select information form a database based on criteria that crosses multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image: Three of my database tables]

[image: Other three database tables]

I have a problem where I need to select the Project Number, Controlling Department Number, Department Manager's Lname, address, and birthdate for each project located in Stafford. I am having trouble getting the results I want.

I tried:

```
SELECT PROJECT.PNUMBER, PROJECT.DNUM, EMPLOYEE.LNAME, EMPLOYEE.ADDRESS, EMPLOYEE.BDATE
FROM PROJECT, EMPLOYEE, DEPARTMENT
WHERE PLOCATION = 'STAFFORD' AND DEPARTMENT.MGRSSN = EMPLOYEE.SSN;
```

And Got:

```
+---------+------+---------+-------------------------+-----------+
| PNUMBER | DNUM | LNAME   | ADDRESS                 | BDATE     |
| 30      | 4    | WONG    | 683 VOSS, HOUSTON, TX   | 08-DEC-55 |
| 10      | 4    | WONG    | 683 VOSS, HOUSTON, TX   | 08-DEC-55 |
| 30      | 4    | WALLACE | 291 BERRY, BELLAIRE, TX | 20-JUN-41 |
+---------+------+---------+-------------------------+-----------+
```

But what I should have gotten is (or what I wanted):

```
+---------+------+---------+-------------------------+-----------+
| PNUMBER | DNUM | LNAME   | ADDRESS                 | BDATE     |
| 10      | 4    | WALLACE | 391 BERRY, BELLAIRE, TX | 20-JUN-41 |
| 30      | 4    | WALLACE | 291 BERRY, BELLAIRE, TX | 20-JUN-41 |
+---------+------+---------+-------------------------+-----------+
```

Can anyone help me figure out what is wrong with my sql statement? *sorry I wasn't able to figure out how to format this*

Comment: +1 haven't seen a well written question in a while.

Comment: Because this is a homework problem, and the o.p. pasted the er diagram from the question.

Comment: This is a *homework* problem???  OMFG, are they *still* teaching this 20 year out-of-date syntax in college?!?  I wouldn't show this to any prospective employers.  And not coincidentally, the problem that you are having is that you haven't placed proper conditions on your Joins, which would be obvious if you were using modern syntax in your `FROM` clause.

Comment: It must be.  Nobody in there right mind would be using SSN's as keys!  The whole schema makes me ill to look at, but its a fun problem to work on.

Comment: Once you have copy pasted one of the following answers dont not forget to put the last line in you code it goes something like -- Powered By Stack Overflow dont forget to put two -- otherwise code will break :)

Comment: All I'm saying is he better up vote my answer or I'm telling his teacher.

Comment: lollllllllll @DanielGimenez

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, you're missing out the join on `DEPARTMENT` and `PROJECT`.

I'd use explicit joins rather than the outdated `where` syntax:

```
select
  PROJECT.PNUMBER,
  PROJECT.DNUM, 
  EMPLOYEE.LNAME,
  EMPLOYEE.ADDRESS
  -- and so on with the EMPLOYEE fields
from
  PROJECT
inner join
  DEPARTMENT
  on DEPARTMENT.DNUMBER = PROJECT.DNUM
inner join
  EMPLOYEE
  on EMPLOYEE.SSN = DEPARTMENT.MGRSSN
where
  PROJECT.PLOCATION = 'Stafford'
```

But with the old syntax:

```
select
  PROJECT.PNUMBER,
  PROJECT.DNUM, 
  EMPLOYEE.LNAME,
  EMPLOYEE.ADDRESS
  -- and so on with the EMPLOYEE fields
from
  PROJECT, DEPARTMENT, EMPLOYEE
where
  PROJECT.PLOCATION = 'Stafford'
  and DEPARTMENT.DNUMBER = PROJECT.DNUM -- This was the missing bit
  and EMPLOYEE.SSN = DEPARTMENT.MGRSSN
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this

```
select p.pnumber, d.dnumber,e.lname, e.[address], e.bdate
from department D 
inner join project P on D.dnumber = P.dnum
inner join employee E on e.ssn = D.mgrssn
where p.location = 'STAFFORD'
```

Answer (score 2):

Your table joins aren't correct.  You needed to join department to project.

```
SELECT p.PNUMBER, p.DNUM, e.LNAME, e.ADDRESS, e.BDATE
FROM Project p
INNER JOIN Department d ON d.DNUMBER = p.DNUM
INNER JOIN Employee e ON e.ssn = d.MGRSSN
WHERE p.PLOCATION = 'STAFFORD';
```

Maybe you haven't learned about other join types yet.  This should also work based on what you've got:

```
SELECT PROJECT.PNUMBER, PROJECT.DNUM, EMPLOYEE.LNAME, EMPLOYEE.ADDRESS, EMPLOYEE.BDATE
FROM PROJECT, EMPLOYEE, DEPARTMENT
WHERE PLOCATION = 'STAFFORD' 
  AND DEPARMENT.DNUMBER = PROJECT.DNUM
  AND DEPARTMENT.MGRSSN = EMPLOYEE.SSN;
```